# How set a permission to write but not delete a directory on linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to set a permission to directory as a root user.
So that "root" user itself is able to create/write files/sub-directories in main directory but not able to delete the main directly or its sub directories.

I need to make this sure so that accidentally I should not delete the main directory or its sub-directories.

Comment: You can't, if you set write permissions it allows the user to delete it as well.

Comment: @alfasin :( not a single option is there to do it? any other thing to avoid accidentally loss!!

Comment: Yes, create daily/hourly backups :) see: http://serverfault.com/questions/125320/chmod-to-prevent-deletion-of-file-directory

Answer (score 0):

Set your file ownership to root by using the following command:

`$ sudo chown root directory-name`

Afterwards, execute the following command for making the directory immutable (i.e.: not deletable):

`$ sudo chattr +i directory-name`